# WCF service problem with Windows XP client

Tags: wcf

I have a program for Windows Application with the Bank uses a WCF service.
 Several Windows 7 client using this service are working well, one of the Windows XP client, and when the service is connected and started working, service to any of the other client does not respond; until Windows XP client relationship is discontinued.
 Thanks and respect.

Comment: that service, what exactly do?